# How to get an unknown point from a line

Tags: geometry

I know the coordinates of the two green dots and I know that I want the red dot to be 10 units away in the x axis.

What is the fastest way to get the y coordinate of the red point?

[image]

Comment: do you have the equation of this line?

Comment: @Dr.SonnhardGraubner No I don't I only have the x and y coordinates of the 2 green dots. I can get the equation using those two points though. Or maybe I cant I think I don't know the y intercept

Comment: Well you have $2$ known points, so you can get easily compute the equation of the line, right?

Comment: I don't think I can find the y intercept. Is there a way to find the equation of a line without the y intercept?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Calculate the slope $s$ of the line using the known coordinates. Then, if $(x,y)$ are the coordinates of the green point nearer to the red one, you get the unknown coordinates as $(x-10, y-10s)$. The intercept is not necessary for this problem.

Comment: If you reflect this image vertically, the red point will be on the right and you're formula will be (x + 10, ???). How does the y change in this scenario

Comment: Yes, reflecting vertically you get $(x+10, y+10s)$ (note that in this case the slope has become negative, so that $y$ again decreases).